# Set cookie accessible by cross domain image api

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have a number of domains `lorem.com`, `ipsum.com` and `dolor.com` etc. They all access images through a central image API `myapi.com`. I need `myapi.com` to be able to know the screen size and width of the requesting client. I am thinking of using a solution similar to the one described here: https://css-tricks.com/server-side-mustard-cut/

TLDR: A small javascript function finds out the width and height of the screen and then saves that to a cookie. Requests to the image api should have that cookie included in the header so the server can figure out how large of an image to send back.

The problem is this is cross domain. `lorem.com` has an image tag as such `<img src="http://www.myapi.com/image1" />` but the cookie won't be included in that request because it was set by a script running on a page from `lorem.com`

The solutions I am finding online involve iframes and fake image tags with `display:none` that actually call a php script from the 3rd party domain to set the cookie.

The problem is I need set the cookie client side with the proper height and width information. I can't use a php script to set that because the php script doesn't know the height and width.

Is there some non-hacky way to go about this that doesn't involve iframes or roundabout solutions? Thanks!

Comment: the solution will always be "roundabout" in some way - I've got the germination of three ideas. 1 - using redirects, 2 -  loading the images dynamically using javascript, 3 - rather than img tags, use css background image (this one would best be if you have a set number of images for a set block of dimensions)

Comment: Thanks - I've already decided that I do need to load the images 'normally' and that somehow the server needs to be provided with the width and height of the client device along with that image request. Those requirements unfortunately can't be changed. As to how I can get that device resolution information sent along with the request - that's what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: why don't you want to load img dynamic - i.e. using javascript?

Comment: I want to make my function able to work along side a lazy-loading library. If I decide to load the image dynamically then it'll make things more difficult for the function to co-exist because now there will be two functions trying to dynamically load an image. Also I just like the simplicity and streamlined-ness of not using any extra js to load an image.

Comment: well, cross site cookies are out - so I can only suggest what I've suggested

Answer (score 0):

Here are two options:

1) use the JavaScript to update the img url with height and width information as query Params in the image url itself rather than relying on cookie e.g. ”/>

2) if you have to use cookies, than if you control myapi.com as well then you can spin an endpoint their which take the client width and height param and in response return set-cookie header. Since the call is made to myapi.com, browser will let it set cookie for myapi.com and it would passed to subsequent calls to that domain, though you would not able to access this cookie from JavaScript since you are not running under myapi.com